# Enable or disable ASP.NET WebForms controls based on CssClass

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I want to enable or disable ASP.NET Contorls based on CssClass, for example I set insert CssClass for one button in ASP.NET Page and check if user have permission to do insert if user have permission I'll enable the button, if not I'll disable the button.

Please note I want to write logic that apply DRY I don't want to write code in every page.

I have 2 scenarios in my mind:

1-Select the controls in Code-Behind using C#, but I have one difficulty in this I'm using BaseClass approach Web.UI.Page --> BaseClass --> MasterPage --> Page  I user the following code snippet and it always return null `this.Controls.OfType<WebControl>().Where(i => i.CssClass == "insert")` because this will select controls in BaseClass only.

2-Create WebMethod to select the permission from code behind and using jQuery select elements by class and enable or disable them based on the permission.

Please give me your opinions and tell me if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish(must) to hide them using their CssClass property, it's probably best to do it on the server, in your base class, as described in your scenario 1. However do remember that `this.Controls` is only one level down in the control tree. If you wish to include all controls, you need to scan the control tree recursively. In order to also achieve this on dynamic content (such as generated `ItemTemplates` in a `ListView` etc.) You need to make sure to do it when everything has rendered.

Doing this on the client is not to recommend, since it's not hard for a malicious user to just open the dev tools and display the insert button again

However you should probably consider the purpose of the CssClass property. It is not really suited for what you're trying to do; it is really intended to apply the styling.

If you are using ASP.NET's Membership Provider and it's Role Provider, you can use the [asp:LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) to limit rendering like so:

```
<asp:LoginView runat="server">
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="CanInsert"> <!--Roles can be anything-->
            <ContentTemplate>
                <!--Insert button or w/e here-->
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

If you are not using the built-in membership provider, rolling your own `LoginView` isn't particularly difficult, and it makes things very DRY yet easy to change

Comment: I'm not using built-in membership provider and I've done scenario number 1 and it's working thanks @Christoffer Mansfield

Answer (score 0):

if u want do this from servers  side u have  many way to do that

1- create 2 css class one for hide and another for show then at page load change css of contorl

*- when u change csscalass property at page load becuase when all control rendered get your peroperty selected for cssclass

for your problem u can find control from form  hierarchical  from contentplaceholder

but u can hide your control acording permision from master page  every page load